# How to copy a file in internal storage to another folder in internal storage in flutter(Android)?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to copy a file in internal storage to another folder in the internal storage. The file I want to copy existed earlier and it wasn't written by the app. I have requested legacy external storage too. I requested permission and accepted it too. But when I try to copy the file it gives me an error.

This is the error

```
E/flutter (32658): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 
FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/sdcard/Documents/Maths paper.pdf', path = 
'/sdcard/Maths paper.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter (32658): #0      _File.copy.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:328:9)
E/flutter (32658): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (32658): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (32658): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I don't know why internal storage is called as sdcard. But in my phone's  file explorer show that as internal storage(found using android studio device file explorer).

This is the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
....
```

I use permission_handler package to request permission.https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

This is the main.dart file.

```
  void _grantPermission () async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {

    } else {
      await Permission.storage.request();
      status = await Permission.storage.status;
      print(status);
    }
 }

// This function runs when I pressed a button.
void _saveFile() async {
    var file = File('/sdcard/Maths paper.pdf');
    file.copy("/sdcard/Documents/Maths paper.pdf");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _grantPermission();
  }
```

Comment: Use file.exists() and file.canRead()  before you try to copy.

Comment: @blackapps when I print file.exists() it prints this. I/flutter (32658): Instance of 'Future<bool>'. But there is no file.canRead()

Comment: You should not print it but use it in the code: if ( !file.exists()) { ...sorry file does not existy... return;}

Comment: @blackapps That file exists and gives the same error again. To confirm that exists. I ran following code. print(await file.exists()) and it printed true.

Comment: But it should be readable. Just try to open an inputstream for the file and try to read some bytes. Which Android version on used device?

Comment: @blackapps Flutter can't open or read that file. And the android version is 10

Comment: Did you request legacy external storage in manifest? And you did not tell how that file landed there. You should have started with it.

Comment: @blackapps I have requested legacy external storage in manifest. And that file wasn't created by my app and it was there earlier

Comment: Try to pick the file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235794/discussion-between-lovinduli-and-blackapps).